# Business phone number and mobile phone number are two fields getting same data why?

Tags: oracle, report

```
 (select pp.PHONE_NUMBER from per_phones pp where pp.person_id = papf.person_id
         and pp.phone_type= 'W1' and rownum<2
         AND    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pp.DATE_FROM(+) AND nvl(pp.DATE_TO(+),trunc(sysdate))) Per_BUS_PH,



   (select pp.PHONE_NUMBER from per_phones pp where pp.person_id = papf.person_id
     and pp.phone_type= 'WM' and rownum<2
     AND    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pp.DATE_FROM(+) AND nvl(pp.DATE_TO(+),trunc(sysdate))) Per_MBL_BUS, 



   (select pp.PHONE_NUMBER from per_phones pp where pp.person_id = papf.person_id
     and pp.phone_type= 'HM' and rownum<2
     AND    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pp.DATE_FROM(+) AND nvl(pp.DATE_TO(+),trunc(sysdate))) Per_MBL_HME   ,


   (select pp.PHONE_NUMBER from per_phones pp where pp.person_id = papf.person_id
     and pp.phone_type= 'H1' and rownum<2
      AND    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pp.DATE_FROM(+) AND nvl(pp.DATE_TO(+),trunc(sysdate))) Per_HME_PH from 
            per_persons pp,
            per_all_people_f papf;
```

Here why I am getting business phone number and mobile business number same.?
It should be different and how can i get different phone number for both field which added I added in Oracle BI report..?

Comment: Sample data, your current wrong result and your expected result for that data would be useful.

Comment: What is the reason for `(+)`? - the subqueries do not make any join.

Comment: `where rownum < 2` is certainly *restricting* something. I presume you used it to avoid TOO-MANY-ROWS error. But, what happens if you run those queries standalone (not in report, but in SQL*Plus, separately from each other)? Besides, are you **sure** that someone didn't enter exactly the same phone numbers into *business* and *mobile business* columns?